# Using CSS Grid, how can I make grid items autoflow based on one of their preceding sibling items?

Tags: css-grid

I have a grid where I am making the first row column headers and each subsequent row the column items. There will be a dynamic number of column headers and a dynamic number of items (rows) under each column, so I can't use a grid template with hardcoded values for the number of rows or columns.

I'm trying to make the implicit grid autoflow the items into their correct order. I've got the column headers autoflowing correctly, but the items underneath the columns are not flowing into their correct columns.

In my example, all the 1.n items should be underneath "Column 1", all the 2.n items should be underneath "Column 2" and all the 3.n items should be underneath "Column 3".

I was thinking of maybe using the preceding `.column-header` for each `.column-item`, but I don't know how to do that. I'm not even sure if that's the best way to do this.

```css
main {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: row;
}

main > div{
    width: 145px;
    height: 90px;
}

.column-header {
    grid-row-start: 1;
    background-color: rgb(247, 244, 244);
    border: 1px solid grey;
    align-items:center;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.column-item {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div class="column-header">Column 1</div>
    <div class="column-item">1.1</div>
    <div class="column-item">1.2</div>
    <div class="column-item">1.3</div>
    <div class="column-item">1.4</div>
    <div class="column-header">Column 2</div>
    <div class="column-item">2.1</div>
    <div class="column-item">2.2</div>
    <div class="column-item">2.3</div>
    <div class="column-item">2.4</div>
    <div class="column-item">2.5</div>
    <div class="column-item">2.6</div>
    <div class="column-item">2.7</div>
    <div class="column-header">Column 3</div>
    <div class="column-item">3.1</div>
    <div class="column-item">3.2</div>
</main>
```

Comment: Why not use `display: flex;`? Then you could dynamically create more flex columns with javascript and add more items to each column. I think that would be the easiest way, right? Is there a specific reason why you need to use Grid?

Comment: I'm learning CSS Grid, so I was hoping to achieve this with only grid. If this is a limitation of grid, then so be it. But I'd love to master Grid for complex layouts.

Comment: That is not how grid works, Given your html structure you can select all `.column-item` that follows the first `.column-header` and assign them the correct column [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/jwz178yf/), However if the grid columns are dynamic then i'm not sure if there's a pure CSS solution, Maybe with a different html structure.